# Which Browsers support TACK?

Tags: tls, certificates, web-browser, browser-extensions

[TACK](http://tack.io) is an IETF draft that allows certificate pinning for a TLS web server, provided the clients' browsers support it. Unlike the certificate pinning feature available with HSTS preloading, the server's operator is not committing to a particular certificate in the chain (and hence typically to a particular root or intermediary CA), instead retaining his own (offline) key that can be used to authorize the use of a new server TLS certificate.

Which browsers support TACK? Are there extensions to add support to browsers that do not otherwise support it?

Comment: Tag wishlist: `certificate-pinning` or `TLS-certificate-pinning`

Comment: You said it, this is still a draft. No official server support. No official browser support. Almost nobody is taking this seriously, and that's not just me, that's [basically what they're saying about their own project](https://lists.riseup.net/www/arc/tack/2014-01/msg00001.html). In my personal opinion, this is a dead/dying project.

Comment: That link in itself is a good answer, but not your summary of it. Otherwise: Many drafts get implemented before (if ever) becoming a standard, especially in web servers and web browsers. Just consider HSTS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Question.  TACK is a "dynamic pinning" solution to the broken Certificate Authority model we all depend on today.  A competitor is Google's Certificate Transparency (CT).

Status of TACK is

- No browsers currently support it.
- There are no browser extensions to enable it.
- The [last posting](https://lists.riseup.net/www/arc/tack/2014-01/msg00001.html) from the developers (January, 2014) is that it is entirely up to the browsers to support it and that we "hope we'll get more progress in 2014".

Comment: CT has a different purpose. It can't _prevent_ a targeted MITM that is in progress, especially if the CA is complacent or the root certificate is stolen (after all, CT relies on the honesty of a CA).